# Specific Chromecast not appearing on a specific laptop

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, projector, chromecast

Good afternoon. I have multiple Chromecast devices on my network. A specific laptop can not seem to find a specific chromecast. It is configured like all the others, and the other chromecast devices appear to work just fine, but the chromecast specific to that room does not appear for that teacher. Likewise, a teacher in another room connects to their chromecast device multiple times, then suddenly can not find that specific chromecast device, but can see the others. Has anyone else ran into this issue, and if so , how did you solve it?

For further information: The Chromecast Devices are connected to Epson Projectors. The teacher uses Google Chrome on a Windows 7 laptop to Cast (either the tab or desktop) to the Chromecast Device.

Firmware is updated on all the chromecast devices, and the laptops themselves are updated. And I can see the chromecast device from my laptop that has NOT connected up multiple times, so the chromecast device is active.

Thanks!